# How can I set same class DIV's height as highest div height

Tags: html, css

I've 3 same class `divs` and `divs` height value is auto, how can I set same class divs height to higher div height?
[Same Class Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKASm.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please give live code in codepen

Comment: Post code, not a picture of code and create a [MCVE] to show your problem properly.  If you're going to be lazy, then don't expect to get any help

Comment: You can use CSS3 flex/flexbox. For more, post better requirement and code you tried so far with the help of SO Snippet.

Comment: @ram Ofcourse;  https://codepen.io/buraktuncbilek/pen/eybeRa

Comment: @Buraktncblk Change the height property to 250Px .so that all the div's has the same height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use

> display:flex

for your container in Modern Browsers

and for Compatibilty in Older Browser Such as Internet Explorer You can Use

> display:table-cell

in each div

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use css flex on container. I write an example below.

CSS

```
.box{
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-container{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    foo<br>foo<br>foo
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    foo<br>foo
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use flexbox for this:

a very useful online tool: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

example:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-item {
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    background: gray;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        Test <br />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        Test <br />Test <br />Test <br />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        Test <br />Test <br />Test <br />Test <br />Test <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add A wrapper row.

HTML

```
      <div class="row">
      <div class="checklist">
        <table> <!-- asp controls:CheckListBox -->
          <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist">
        <table> <!-- asp controls:CheckListBox -->
          <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist">
        <table> <!-- asp controls:CheckListBox -->
          <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <td>item1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>item2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.checklist {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 120px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;      flex: 1;
}
.checklist table {
  height: auto;
 width: 160px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery very easily.

`Algorithm`
1. Set a height for the checkbox elements
2. Get the div with the most checkbox elements
3. Set the height for all checklist elements by multiplying the most checkbox elements with the checkbox element height.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    var mostChecklist,
        checklists = [ ],
        checkboxHeight = '30'; // you can modify this value

    // Get all checklist length
    JQuery('.checklist')
    .each( function( i, checklist ) {
        // Get all input checkbox in checklist
        checklists.push( 
            jQuery( checklist ).children('input:checkbox').length 
        );
    });

    // Get max number in checklists array
    mostChecklist = checklists.reduce(
        function( a, b ) {
            return Math.max( a, b );
        }
    );

    // Set the height of all checklist elements
    jQuery('.checklist').css( 'height', checkboxHeight * mostChecklist +'px' );
});
```